# Saving controls changes without save button

Tags: c#, database, wpf, controls

Currently I'm learning about C# and WPF.

I have created a settings window with multiple tabs, each tab contain multiple controls to edit, some of them are custom made (percentage slider or up/down integer input [image]) and some of them are default textboxes and such.

These are all set in my SettingsViewModel class:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : BaseVM
{
    #region Private Members

    private SettingsDataModel _settings;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IntegerUpDownViewModel Age { get; set; }

    public IntegerUpDownViewModel Confidence { get; set; }

    public PercentageSliderViewModel Activity { get; set; }

    public PercentageSliderViewModel Skills { get; set; }

    #endregion
    [...]
```

I'm using local database file to store the data (Sqlite).

**My question is:**
I'm wondering, what is the proper way to save all these controls in MVVM once they are edited? The key thing is, I don't want to use a save button. I want to update the data in database once the control are edited.

Been trying to save them with `OnPropertyChanged` event in my `SettingsViewModel` but this works really bad and slow... especially for the percentage sliders.

Comment: For properties that are updated multiple times within a short time (like percentage sliders), set the Delay property of your Binding to something like 500 milliseconds).

Comment: @RogerLeblanc Yeah, but the OnPropertyChanged is bad in general since I have to subscribe to PropertyChanged event in my settings constructor for ALL of the controls. Just imagine 50 controls and 50 event listeners https://pastebin.com/raw/02wJK3cA . Kinda overkill to be honest.

Comment: This looks like a easy question, yet none have a solution for :-)

Comment: You could set the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` property for the binding to `LostFocus`, this initiates the PropertyChanged event only when the control loses focus.

Comment: @B.Feenstra Could have done that, but like I said - especially for controls like `PercentageSlider` I'm updating other properties like text value, statuses etc. Thats why it has to be "live".

Comment: Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is definitely the way to keep your bindings between the view and view model in sync. I believe the reason it was slow in this case is that you are constantly writing to the database which is very expensive. No matter how you are passing the data between the view and the view model, if you are constantly writing to SQLite it will probably be slow. Is there some event or other UI element that can trigger a save when you leave this view, rather than a dedicated save button?